# How to arrange dataset of species list from most abundant species to least abundant species

Tags: r

I have a dataset that looks something like the below. Is there a line of code in R to arrange the different species from most abundant (occurs the most in the column) to least abundant? Thank you!

```
df <- tibble::tribble(
  ~name,
  "Species A",
  "Species A",
  "Species B",
  "Species C",
  "Species A",
  "Species C",
  "Species B",
  "Species A"
)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use `table`, sort this, use `match` to the `names` and `order`.

```
df[order(match(df$name, names(sort(table(df$name), decreasing=TRUE)))),]
## A tibble: 8 × 1
#  name     
#  <chr>    
#1 Species A
#2 Species A
#3 Species A
#4 Species A
#5 Species B
#6 Species B
#7 Species C
#8 Species C
```

Or using `split`:

```
. <- split(seq_len(nrow(df)), df$name)
df[unlist(.[order(lengths(.), decreasing=TRUE)], FALSE, FALSE),]
## A tibble: 8 × 1
#  name     
#  <chr>    
#1 Species A
#2 Species A
#3 Species A
#4 Species A
#5 Species B
#6 Species B
#7 Species C
#8 Species C
```

Or in case only the vector should be sorted:

```
. <- sort(table(df$name), decreasing=TRUE)
rep(names(.), .)
#[1] "Species A" "Species A" "Species A" "Species A" "Species B" "Species B"
#[7] "Species C" "Species C"
```

Answer (score 2):

There is the function `fct_infreq` from the forcats package to order elements by their abundance:

```r
library(tidyverse)

data <- tibble(
  species = c(
  "Species A",
  "Species A",
  "Species B",
  "Species C",
  "Species A",
  "Species C",
  "Species B",
  "Species A")
)

data %>%
  mutate(species = species %>% fct_infreq()) %>%
  arrange(species)
#> # A tibble: 8 × 1
#>   species  
#>   <fct>    
#> 1 Species A
#> 2 Species A
#> 3 Species A
#> 4 Species A
#> 5 Species B
#> 6 Species B
#> 7 Species C
#> 8 Species C
```

<sup>Created on 2022-05-11 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

You can also `reorder` the factor by number of occurrences, and then `sort` the factor:

```r
data$species <- reorder(data$species, data$species, FUN = length) |>
  sort(decreasing = T)
```

output

```
data

    species  
1 Species A
2 Species A
3 Species A
4 Species A
5 Species C
6 Species C
7 Species B
8 Species B
```

Answer (score 0):

**data.table solution**

```
library(data.table)

data <- setDT(data)[, n := .N, species][order(-n, species)][, n := NULL]
```

**output**

```
data

#      species
# 1: Species A
# 2: Species A
# 3: Species A
# 4: Species A
# 5: Species B
# 6: Species B
# 7: Species C
# 8: Species C
```

**data**

```
data <- tibble(
  species = c(
  "Species A",
  "Species A",
  "Species B",
  "Species C",
  "Species A",
  "Species C",
  "Species B",
  "Species A")
)
```